# Getting a binding error, when trying to create a datapager for a listview without datasource control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to create a datapager for my list view on the bottom of the page. When i bind the listview without the datapager i get no error and all of the content gets listed like it should. But when i try to create a datapager i get an error that says: **list needs a datasource or need an ICollection as a datasource if AllowPaging is true**

Here is my listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstAllProducts" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a style="color: black" href="ProductInfo.aspx?id=<%# Eval("itemId") %>">
                <div class="wrpInnerItem hvr-fade">
                    <div class="innerItem">
                        <p><%#Eval("gtin")%></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="innerItem">
                        <p><%#Eval("brandName")%></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="innerItem">
                        <p><%#Eval("functionalName")%></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="innerItem">
                        <p><%#Eval("unitDescription")%></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="innerItem">
                        <p><%#Eval("articleNr")%></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

And here is the datapager:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstAllProducts" PageSize="12">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

And here is where i bind the data for the listview in the page load:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lstAllProducts.DataSource = svc.GetAllItemsOverview().OrderByDescending(i => i.id);
            lstAllProducts.DataBind();
        }
```

I have tried to follow the guide in this link. http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/paging-listview-using-datapager-without-using-datasource-control

hope some of you have a suggestion on why it wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `DataPager` needs complete data for calculating the page numbers but you are assigning `IEnumerable<T>` to your `ListView` which will be resolved while binding the data (You can read about `LINQ Deferred Execution`).

To solve the issue simply enumerate the results using `ToArray` or `ToList`:-

```
lstAllProducts.DataSource = svc.GetAllItemsOverview()
                               .OrderByDescending(i => i.id)
                               .ToArray();
```

Comment: This works! thanks. Now i just get a lot of empty elements when switching between the pages.

Comment: @KevinJensen - Yeah it depends on whatever data you have (everything will be loaded when you call `.ToArray`), Basically keeping all records in memory is not preferred so you will have to search for alternatives.

Comment: do you have any suggestions? or mabye a link where i could see another way of populating my list

Comment: @KevinJensen - Basically the trick here is to set the `startIndex` & `PageSize` dynamically, you can refer to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142326/Effective-paging-with-List-View-control-in-ASP-NET)